# UINavigationBar rotation works incorrect when it is embedded in UIContainerView

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, landscape-portrait, autorotate

I have Container with UINavigationController in it.
[image]

When I rotate device in Landscape Mode the UINavigationBar is cropped and looks like this: 
    [image]

When the UINavigationCOntroller is not embedded in Container View it autorotates correctly. Can somebody help me to deal with this strange behaviour?

Comment: Have your tried setting top constraint of container to top layout guide?

Comment: Yes I added all constraints

Comment: What are the `constraints` set to for your `container` and your `navigation controller`?

Comment: ContainerView.Top = TopLayoutGuide.Bottom - 20 and navigation controller is embedded in container witch does not need constraints